# How to filter combined search outputs with OR logic

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a working Google Sheets filter formula that combines different searches of the same range.

In the formula below, I'm searching column AA in the *REFS* worksheet.

I enter search terms into any or all cells AA1 - AD1 in the *current* sheet.

This formula searches for each of these criteria and displays rows matching *ALL* search terms.

```
=IFNA(filter(REFS!$A$3:$AA,
IF(AA1<>"",SEARCH(AA1,REFS!AA3:AA),"")+
IF(AB1<>"",SEARCH(AB1,REFS!AA3:AA),"")+
IF(AC1<>"",SEARCH(AC1,REFS!AA3:AA),"")+
IF(AD1<>"",SEARCH(AD1,REFS!AA3:AA),"")),"")
```

This works fine whether I supply one or multiple criteria.

However, this is an *ALL* search. It only displays rows matching *all* search criteria.

I need an *OR* version of this to display rows that match *any* search criteria.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171971/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Charlie you now have two answers using two different assumptions. The goal of this site is to have great questions and answers.  Please help us to help you and people who come after. [edit] your question based on the suggestions and  provide feedback on the answers so we have clarity about  what you wanted. 

Answer (score 1):

To search each row in `REFS!A3:AA` for *partial* and case-insensitive matches of any of the text strings in `AA1:AD1`, use `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=ifna( 
  filter( 
    REFS!A3:AA, 
    regexmatch( 
      REFS!AA3:AA, 
      "(?i)" & textjoin("|", true, AA1:AD1) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Note that this only works as long as none of the text strings in `AA1:AD1` contain [regex special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping).

Comment: The OP needs to post an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

## Not Search

SEARCH locates the position of a text string within another text string, not a value in a range.

Example:

```
=SEARCH("bob", "jimbob") 
=4
```

## Solution

To FILTER a range based on a list of values use:

```
=FILTER(range, COUNTIF(list, column))
```

For example:

```
=FILTER(REFS!A3:AA, 
   COUNTIF(AA1:AD1, REFS!AA3:AA))
```

See:   [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en)